# avoid injecting default value in table

Tags: php, html

I want to inject select option value in table.But I don't want to inject default value.

```
<select name="gender">
<option selected>  Select </option>
<option value="male">    Male   </option>
<option value="female">  Female </option>
</select>
```

I want to show warning as required attribute.now I have a problem If gender is not chosen the word 'select' is injucted in database.I dont want to inject select word.I want to show warning as required field id gender is not chosen(with default value)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
<select name="gender" placeholder="Select">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="male">    Male   </option>
<option value="female">  Female </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **require** attribute and also assign empty value to `select` option simply like

`<option value="">  Select </option>`

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

```
<select name="gender" required>
<option value="">  Select </option>
<option value="male">    Male   </option>
<option value="female">  Female </option>
</select>
```